# Can we create "record count" based window in spark streaming?

Tags: java, spark-streaming

I need to do computations based on previous and next element of JavaDstream. But in order to access those I need to create a sliding window based on record counts.

```
        JavaStreamingContext javaStreamingContext = createSteamingContext(settings);
    JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> pivotedKafkaData = KafkaSource.getStream(javaStreamingContext, settings);
    JavaDStream<VoyageData> voyageData = pivotedKafkaData.map(Tuple2::_2)
        .map(StreamProcessor::getStandardizedRecords)
        .map(Functions::getVoyageDataRecords);

    JavaDStream<VoyageData> windowedVoyageData = voyageData.window(Durations.seconds(4),Durations.seconds(4));
```

In my code I have created a time based window, Now the question is, How can I access previous , current and next record from it.

Comment: pls accept the answer if it is helpful :)

Comment: Did you figure out how to achieve it using Spark streaming?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the updateStateByKey(func) transformation for statefull transformation for more understanding checkout below github example and blogs

https://github.com/phalodi/stateful-wordcount-spark

https://blog.knoldus.com/2015/06/24/stateful-transformation-on-dstream-in-apache-spark-with-example-of-wordcount/

http://www.spark.tc/stateful-spark-streaming-using-transform/